# How to use RuboCop::Cop::Rails::ApplicationRecord on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubocop

I want to use ApplicationRecord Cop on Rails 4.
I already added 'self.abstract_class = true' .

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

And this file is written 'minimum_target_rails_version 5.0'.

https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/rails/application_record.rb

So I created custom_cop like this.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module CustomCops
  # @example
  #
  #  # good
  #  class Rails5Model < ApplicationRecord
  #    # ...
  #  end
  #
  #  # bad
  #  class Rails4Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  #    # ...
  #  end
  class MustApplicationRecord < RuboCop::Cop::Cop
    MSG = 'Models should subclass `ApplicationRecord`.'
    SUPERCLASS = 'ApplicationRecord'
    BASE_PATTERN = '(const (const nil? :ActiveRecord) :Base)'
    include RuboCop::Cop::EnforceSuperclass
    

    def autocorrect(node)
      lambda do |corrector|
        corrector.replace(node.source_range, self.class::SUPERCLASS)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I got an error running rspec, like this.

```
Failure/Error:
         class MustApplicationRecord < RuboCop::Cop::Cop
           MSG = 'Models should subclass `ApplicationRecord`.'
           SUPERCLASS = 'ApplicationRecord'
           BASE_PATTERN = '(const (const nil? :ActiveRecord) :Base)'
           include RuboCop::Cop::EnforceSuperclass


           def autocorrect(node)
             lambda do |corrector|
               corrector.replace(node.source_range, self.class::SUPERCLASS)

NameError:
         uninitialized constant CustomCops::RuboCop
```

Do you know how to solve this error, or other method( like override 'minimum_target_rails_version 5.0' to 'minimum_target_rails_version 4.0' ) ?

### versions

```
Rails 4.2.8
ruby 2.6.6
rubocop 0.80.1
RSpec 3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `RuboCop` is not defined.

You need to `require 'rubocop'` somewhere before you define your cop.